# how to get image file name from image encryption

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

My program should encrypt image.

> My question is: How can I display encrypted image

my controller code

```
public function view($slug = NULL){
            $data['post'] = $this->post_model->get_posts($slug);
            $post_id = $data['post']['id'];
            $user_id = $data['post']['user_id'];
            $data['comments'] = $this->comment_model->get_comments($post_id);
            $data['users'] = $this->user_model->get_user($user_id);

            if(empty($data['post'])){
                show_404();
            }

            $data['title'] = $data['post']['title'];

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('posts/view', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of encrypting images? Do you want to prevent interception during transmission?

Comment: i want same image and different name

Comment: Do you mean that the image URL or the displayed image name is different from the file name actually stored in the file system?

Comment: i am using time() function. rename file its working